# issue while Calling same Editor Template with Telerik control multiple times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

My work is on MVC3 with Razor, So this is the Scenario
I have an Editor Template which has a Telerik DropDownList control in it.
 My requirement is to display the same Telerik DropDownList multiple times from the Editor Template by calling the

```
EditorFor(m=>m.Assignee.Options,"OptionsList")
EditorFor(m=>m.Assignee.Options,"OptionsList")
```

So if i do this, the style for both the controls get rendered properly, but the "functionality" of the Telerik DDL gets affected for the second control(it doesn't drop at all), the first one works fine.
Afterwards, i tried to use some other control (here too the control's working was based on jQuery just like Teleriks) and i repeated the above scenario. SAME RESULT.
First control got rendered and worked properly, rest of the repeated controls broke.
I found out that the issue was becoz of the Script(jQuery) that were used by the controls in the Editor Template.
My question is, is it possible to use a **jQuery based control in Editor Template** and make it work for **mulitple times** in the same page?
If so any solution or link which i can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to your name and id attributes having the same values.

In your editor template try making the name and the id attributes unique.

```
@(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
  .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))   //unique
  .HtmlAttributes(new { id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty) + "_wrapper" })  //unique
  .SelectedIndex(...)
  .BindTo(...)
)
```

Comment: yes, it worked. I'm using custom controls like Image Tick V2.0, http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/ i tried with unique name and id's. doesn't work for this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this Image Tick script. Are you rendering checkboxes/radio buttons along with a dropdownlist in your editor template?

Comment: just a static list from ViewModel, actually i'm rendering both.The tough part is where i have to make the script identify that same list is getting repeated.